# how to be able to display the selected data and display it?

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to ask, how to be able to display the selected data and display it ?

### Codeigniter framework

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    $id_shelter = array();
    $nama_shelter = array();
    $shelter = $this->M_shelter->id();
    $data['shelter'] = $shelter;
    foreach($shelter as $all_shelter){
        array_push($id_shelter, $all_shelter->id_shelter);
        array_push($nama_shelter, $all_shelter->nama_shelter);
    }
    $all_data = $this->M_shelter->pengukuran($id_shelter[1], $nama_shelter[1]);
    foreach($all_data as $all){
        $data['suhu']       = $all->suhu;
        $data['tegAC']      = $all->tegAC;
        $data['tegDC']      = $all->tegDC;
        $data['arusAC']     = $all->arusAC;
        $data['arusDC']     = $all->arusDC;
        $data['kondisi_gas']    = $all->kondisi_gas;
        $data['kondisi_pintu']  = $all->kondisi_pintu;
    }
    $data['page']           = "home";
    $data['judul']          = "Beranda";
    $data['deskripsi']      = "Site managament system";
    $this->template->views('home', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
   public function pengukuran($id_shelter, $nama_shelter)
{
    $sql = "select pengukuran.id_shelter as id_shelter, pengukuran.nama_shelter as nama_shelter, parameter.suhu as suhu, parameter.tegAC as tegAC,
    parameter.tegDC as tegDC, parameter.arusAC as arusAC, parameter.arusDC as arusDC, parameter.kondisi_pintu as kondisi_pintu, 
    parameter.kondisi_gas as kondisi_gas from parameter, pengukuran, shelter 
    where (pengukuran.id_shelter = '$id_shelter' and parameter.id_shelter = '$id_shelter') and 
    (shelter.nama_shelter = '$nama_shelter' and pengukuran.nama_shelter = '$nama_shelter')";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $data->result();
}
```

such as the example image. when I select (data 1) on the button it will display its data in the display column under it, as well as when I choose to display (data 2) it will display the data in the column below.
[For image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L726W.jpg)

I hope someone can help me. thanks

Comment: You can just load the bootstrap libraries and use their nav functionality. Here is the link:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/   starting from "JavaScript behavior" heading.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use AJAX and on button change event pass the value of Data1 or Datat2.
In query if u get $_POST['datatype'] then based on that filter data and display in output.